# Curl call failing

Tags: php, curl, response, libcurl

I am making the following php curl call:

```
$installScript = curl_init('http://blah.com');
    curl_setopt($installScript, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($installScript, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($installScript, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=" . $_POST['user'] . "&password=" . $_POST['password']);
    curl_setopt($installScript, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($installScript, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($installScript, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $canUninstall = curl_exec($installScript);
    curl_close($installScript);
```

Due to some issues, this call seems to be failing intermittently.

Comment: what you get Error message?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what types of usernames or passwords you're using, but you should be url encoding them.

```
curl_setopt($installScript, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=" . urlencode($_POST['user']) . "&password=" .  urlencode($_POST['password']));
```

Comment: Will the curl call fail, if the post parameters are not encoded?

Comment: If someone has a special character in their password it'd make it fail.

Comment: special characters such as?

Comment: &, for example (or most things non-alphanumeric).

Comment: it is failing even with normal characters

Comment: I am thinking, not passing http headers could be an issue? What do you suggest?